# Hypervisor to have VMs for users logging in/out of the host machine?

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, xen

I'm looking for a solution for the following workflow: Let's say I have 4 dedicated users on my CentOS box dedicated for QA purposes. This box has a hypervisor running 4 separate VMs concurrently, their cores/memory split evenly between them. When a user ssh's into the box, the hypervisor gives them their own personal VM. If another user logs into the box at the same time, it serves their VM to them as well.

I've been looking at Xen as a possible hypervisor, but I'm not sure where to start. If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

-Matt

Answer (score 0):

So you want to publish desktops to these users when they login to your server?

IE: Server A is giving users 1-4 a seperate desktop/session each.

You can use a class 1 hypervisor (like xenserver or esxi) and run XEN app and publish your Cent OS desktops to each user.

In order to provide a better response, you may want to elaborate a little more on your current setup and why this is something your looking into. Maybe include current network setup (without saying too much of course), server/os setup, storage space, etc..